# Search and Select Specific package version using Nuget Package Manager

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

How can I search for a specific version of a package using the "Manage Packages" dialog and install in to current project?

I am trying to install "Fluent NHibernate 1.3.0.717", however the search only shows "Fluent NHibernate 1.2.0.712" .

I am aware that I can install specific version using the Package Manager console, but I want to know how can it be done via Manage Packages GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to get a specific version of a package in NuGet Package Manager.

For simplicity the NuGet Pacackage Manager's current behavior is to show the latest versions only. The console offers more control over which versions can be installed.

But, in your case, the dialog should show 1.3.0.717. I filed a bug ([#468](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/468)) against the NuGet Gallery, since 1.2.0.712 is marked as the latest : http://nuget.org/packages/FluentNHibernate/1.3.0.717

Comment: Thx for filing the bug. I see that Drew Miller has already responded. Will keep checking the thread to see if it is resovled.